# Non-const reference type with STL-conforming const Iterator?

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, stl, iterator

I'm working on writing a class that essentially provides a flexible interface to some other data. I would like to iterate over elements using an STL conforming iterator and I'm on the right track by using `boost::iterator_facade` but I have a question regarding conformance that I can't seem to find an official answer to.

Do I have to provide a const iterator for STL conformance?

I'm using `std::shared_ptr<T>&` for the non-const dereferenced type that the iterator provides. If I do provide a const iterator, is it acceptable to provide a `std::shared_ptr<T>&` for my dereferenced type as opposed to a `std::shared_ptr<const T>&`?

I have a feeling that the answer to both is no, but I'm unable to find official sources that validate/invalidate those suspicions. I think the second question is more of a matter of semantics.

Comment: Are you sure you don't want to return references from your iterator? Because then you have at most an input iterator...

Comment: @Deduplicator I think it just strikes me as unusual to return a reference to a `shared_ptr` but I see your point. I'll have to rethink  this interface.

Comment: Is your "other data" writeable? If not, provide only the const iterators.

Comment: @Deduplicator it is writable. On particular about this "other data" is that I'm generating element views, `T`, upon iteration. That's the reason I was providing a shared_ptr to the generated element. In keeping with the scope of the question though, I'll edit the question and assume referenced types.

Comment: Are those shared_ptr's unique to each returned thing, or is it the same base shared_ptr for all in the same container? If it is the latter, shed the `shared_ptr` alltogether.

Comment: The `shared_ptr`s are unique to the underlying entity. That's to say that once one has been generated, it's cached and fully represents the underlying data for a particular entity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is your decision how far the `const` should reach.

The standard way is, just slap a `const` on the element returned (possibly by reference) from the `const_iterator`. That's what the standard library does as well.
So, if the return type for your standard iterator is `std::shared_ptr<T>&`, then the return type for your constant iterator should be `const std::shared_ptr<T>&`.

BTW: Did you read the section of the standard describing requirements for iterators, like:

```
Random Access -> Bidirectional -> Forward -> Input
                                             Output
```

The full container interface provides const iterators as well as non-const iterators.
If you restrict yourself to those algorithms which won't try to get const iterators, you'll be fine omitting them.

Comment: I did review that section and it was certainly helpful in figuring out what operations needed to be supported by the custom iterator, I just wasn't sure best practices with respect to the constness. In any case, thanks for providing some clarity here.

Comment: I think this question is almost an accepted answer, could you clarify whether or not the `const std::shared_ptr<T>&` is a requirement of the const iterator?

Comment: Not using const on the return type allows changing the value (also changing overload resolution), which would remove all value from having a const_iterator in the first place.

Comment: So it's a matter of semantics then which is what I thought. Thanks!